# Adding table via js

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am fetching a template from database in form of header and footer. Now question how can I add table to my body.

```
(function($) {
    "use strict";

    var utilities = window....;
    var createElement = utilities.createElement;

    var createDivElement = function(className) {
        return createElement("div")
            .addClass(className);
    };

    var getCurrentTemplate = function() {
        return window.COMMON_DATA.template || {
            header: null,
            footer: null
        };
    };

    var createCustomerDetailsElement= function(template) {
        var brandHeaderElement = createDivElement("header");
        var brandFooterElement = createDivElement("footer");
        var contentElement = createDivElement("body");
        var CustomerContentElement = createDivElement("content-manager");

        if (template.header) {
            brandHeaderElement.html(template.header);
        }

        contentElement.append(
            createElement("center").text("Customer Details")
                );
        if (template.footer) {
            brandFooterElement.html(template.footer);
        }
        CustomerContentElement
            .append(brandHeaderElement)
            .append(contentElement)
            .append(brandFooterElement);

        return CustomerContentElement;
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var template = getCurrentTemplate();

        $("body").append(createCustomerDetailsElement(template));
    });
} (jQuery));
```

Now I have to add a table which even I am adding data from database as well. Below is my format is an example way. Is there any way I can add the data to table.

```
+--------------+----------------------+
|       Customer Details              |
+--------------+----------------------+
| GuestName    | Johm Smith           |
| CustomerID   | 1234569078           |
| EmailAddress | jsmith@abc123.com    |
| Country      | US                   |
| Birthdate    | 01/01/1992           |
+--------------+----------------------+
```

If you have any question please let me know.

Another question for table above. If I create a another view in my mvc project how can I call it over here? For instance view name is GetCustomerDetails.

Comment: **Note:** the `center` element has been [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center).

Comment: @MatthewJohnson Yes I know I will chang that but besides that do you know what can be done to my post request?

Comment: sorry, I'm not familiar enough with asp.net to be able to help there.  I'm not sure how you're getting the data, or what format it's in.

Comment: You can add table values using model content, pass the model to view thus you can call jQuery to build custom table. Other ways I know that you can pass HTML formatted strings from controller to build your table and execute `Html.Raw(htmltablestring)` on view side.